# Multiple file uploading using pluploadBootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I am using `pluploadBootstrap` widget for multiple file uploading.But after uploading I am getting only the name of the file,and am new to this widget.Please suggest me a solution.I need to upload the uploaded file to a folder.Below is what I had tried.

[image]

The jquery function is

```
if( $.fn.pluploadBootstrap ) {
    $( "#div" ).pluploadBootstrap({

        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,html4',
        url : 'controller/fileUpload',
        max_file_size : '25600kb',
        chunk_size : '6400kb',
        unique_names : true,
        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize : { width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90 },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters : [
            {title : "files", extensions : "jpg, jpeg, gif, png,pdf"}
        ],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : 'plugins/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : 'plugins/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });

}
```

code in controller/fileUpload:

```
Array
(
  [name] => p181eueia91je41itdg8pu6a13ad4.pdf
)
```

Example: http://www.plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with this..

```
if( $.fn.pluploadBootstrap ) {

    $( "#plupload-demo" ).pluploadBootstrap({                             
        runtimes : 'html5',
        url : baseUrl+'/fileUpload',
        max_file_size : '5mb',
        chunk_size : '5mb',
        unique_names : false,
        multipart: true,

        // Resize images on clientside if we can 
        resize : { width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90 },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters : [
            {title : "Files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png,pdf,xlsx"}
        ],
        setup: attachCallbacks

    });

}
```

And in 'fileUpload'

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"userdocs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```